# Dropping columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have written this code to drop a column in my dataset but the message is this

```
df = Data.drop('URL', axis=1)


----> 1 df = Data.drop('URL', axis=1)

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

Was hopping to drop the column using pandas but it did not work

Comment: `Data` should be a pandas dataframe. you probably meant `df.drop()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Hope you are doing well!

Looks like `Data` has type `_io.TextIOWrapper`, but it should be only a `DataFrame` type then you will be able to drop columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3],
        "B": [4, 5, 6],
        "C": [7, 8, 9]
    },
)

print(dummy_df)
#   A  B  C
# 0  1  4  7
# 1  2  5  8
# 2  3  6  9

dummy_df = dummy_df.drop(columns=["B", "C"])

print(dummy_df)
#   A
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
```

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html